# What exactly is Tclass?

Tags: delphi

In my program I do:

```
var aObj: Tobject;
var aObjClassType: Tclass;
....
aObjClassType := aObj.ClassType;
....
aObj.free;
aObj := nil;
....
showmessage(aObjClassType.Classname);
```

this work but I m not quite sure If this is correct, especially when i read the function `TObject.ClassType`

```
function TObject.ClassType: TClass;
begin
  Pointer(Result) := PPointer(Self)^;
end;
```

So does freeing `aObj` will not also free the `aObjClassType` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `TClass` is a class. A `TObject` is an instance. So `obj.ClassType` returns the class, that is the type, of the instance `obj`.

Note that this is the runtime type of the instance rather than the type of the `obj` reference variable. This is relevant when using polymorphism. So if you write

```
var
  shape: TShape;
.... 
shape := TSquare.Create;
```

Then `shape.ClassType` returns `TSquare` even though the `shape` variable is `TShape`.

> So does freeing `aObj` will not also free the `aObjClassType`?

No. Classes are static and created when the module loads and destroyed when the module unloads.

For more detail read the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#TObject_and_TClass

Comment: Wrong. TObject is not an instance. TObject is the ultimate ancestor class for all other classes. TClass is the most basic class reference type. An instance of a class reference type store a class as its value.

Comment: @Marcodor `TObject` is a type. A `TObject` is an instance of that type.

Comment: He asked what `is TClass` not `is a TClass` or `a TObject`. So TClass is a `class reference type`.

Comment: @Marcodor Yes, I was trying to give some context.